# How to edit POST parameters in Firebug?

Tags: jsf, firebug

I am using Firebug on Firefox for Mac in order to see the info about the request data sent to the server and what response is taken from the server. I have a problem with my Spring+Hibernate+JSF+MySQL application; i.e. I cannot persist new objects to the database. In Eclipse, I have an XHTML file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>JSF Spring Hibernate Integration</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .tg {
                border-collapse: separate;
                border-spacing: 0;
                border-color: #ccc;
            }

            .tg td {
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                padding: 10px 5px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 1px;
                overflow: hidden;
                word-break: normal;
                border-color: #ccc;
                color: #333;
                background-color: #fff;
            }

            .tg th {
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight: normal;
                padding: 10px 5px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 1px;
                overflow: hidden;
                word-break: normal;
                border-color: #ccc;
                color: #333;
                background-color: #f0f0f0;
            }

            .tg .tg-4eph {
                background-color: #f9f9f9
            }
        </style>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h1>Add a Person</h1>
        <h:form>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Name</label></td>
                    <td><h:inputText id="Name" value="#{person.name}"></h:inputText>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Country</label></td>
                    <td><h:inputText id="country" value="#{person.country}"></h:inputText>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><h:commandButton
                            action="#{personService.addPerson(person)}" value="Add Person"></h:commandButton>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </h:form>

        <br />
        <h3>Persons List</h3>

        <c:if test="${!empty personService.listPersons()}">
            <table class="tg">
                <tr>
                    <th width="80">Person ID</th>
                    <th width="120">Person Name</th>
                    <th width="120">Person Country</th>
                </tr>
                <ui:repeat value="${personService.listPersons()}" var="person">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${person.id}</td>
                        <td>${person.name}</td>
                        <td>${person.country}</td>
                    </tr>
                </ui:repeat>
            </table>
        </c:if>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I am new to and very inexperienced about Firebug, but while examining GET and POST parameters at the Firebug, I saw something interesting for me. After clicking on 'Add Person' button on JSF view page; the data,which user enters into the Name and Country fields, is sent as POST parameters named `j_idt6:Name` and `j_idt6:country` instead of just 'Name' and 'country'.Also, `javax.faces.ViewState` seems kinda odd to me.Here is the screenshot of it:

[image]

[image]

I am not definitely sure of it, but I suppose that this may cause failure in persisting a new object in my database.Here is my question:How can I edit these parameters on Firebug?How to make them work properly?

Comment: You're asking the Wrong question in order to solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Firebug doesn't let you edit the request parameters, but if you are using Firefox, the built-in dev tools allow this.

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> on Windows/Linux or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> on Mac to get to the *Network* panel
2. Reload the page
3. Select the relevant request to open the side panels
4. Within the *Headers* side panel click on *Edit and Resend*
5. Edit the headers
6. Click *Send*

Comment: thanks for reply.i have followed your explanations, but when i reload the page after all these, i see same 'j_idt6:Name' and 'j_idt6:country' things again:/

Comment: I see what you're saying now - sorry, you can't permanently change the code in the browser - you need to go to the editor to do this.

Comment: thanks again.can you please tell how to open editor?

Comment: I mean open your code in the editor / IDE that you used to write it

Comment: sorry, but i am a little bit confused.i defined name box(or country box) as `<td><h:inputText id="Name" value="#{person.name}"></h:inputText>`  in the xhtml file on Eclipse.should i modify this line in the editor?

Comment: What Sam means is that Firebug and the Firefox DevTools only work on the client side, i.e. within the browser. They can't change the server-side code. To do so you need to use your IDE. Your actual question seems to be rather about how to process the request parameters within JSF/Spring. So I suggest you [read](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.2/javadocs/index.html) their [docs](https://spring.io/guides) and if you still don't know how to handle the request parameters in them, ask a specific question related to that.

Comment: I believe the correct shortcut in Windows is `Ctrl Shift Q`.

Answer (score 0):

Just right-click on the text box and choose *Inspect Element*. Then rename the input as you like by double-clicking on `name` attribute (or click-right + *Edit as HTML*). And repeat those steps for the second input field.

[image: Inline-editing the <code>name</code> attribute of an input]

Or you can modify the POST parameters as @Sam said.

Comment: thanks for reply.i have already edited these input names as you explained.i edit them, click on 'Add Person' button and same parameters are seen again.should i make ctrl+s or something?

Comment: You don't need to save anything, this is a debugging tool. The POST request you sent contains the modified names. The question is , did the request you just sent after editing these inputs has added anything to the Database ( I mean the persisting issue)? if not, then the issue is not related to the input names that're generated by JSF.

Comment: ok, i got your point.the request hasn't added the inputs to mysql again. i don't know what to try next..but thank you much for explanations.